# conjugate gradient method - error estimate

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

According to book (Numerical optimization, Nodal, Wright), the error estimate of CG method is defined as following
$$
\|x_k - x^*\|_A^2 \le \left ( \frac{\lambda_{n - k} - \lambda_1}{\lambda_{n - k} + \lambda_1} \right )^k \| x_0 - x^* \|_A^2,
$$
where $\lambda_n \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_1$.

Is there any numerical reason/explanation, when and why this bounds should not hold for given iteration?

Comment: There should be n instead of 2 in the exponent, right? ;) Plus: I don't understand your question.

Comment: yes, have corrected already... 
my question basically is: does it always-always  hold?

Comment: Sure, it does. Whichever vector you start with.

Comment: minus residual = steepest descent direction